# Transform rows into columns MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `tblColumnNames` and `tblValues` with following structure and example values:

```
tblColumnNames - has two columns with names 'id' and 'ColumnName' 
and following example data:
-------------------------------
id                  ColumnName

0                   columnName1
1                   columnName2
2                   columnName3


tblValues has three columns 'id', 'ColumnId' and 'Value' with following example data:
-------------------------------

id                ColumnId                Value

51                0                       177
52                1                       abcde
53                2                       123
54                0                       40
55                1                       xyz
56                2                       321
```

`ColumnId` corresponds to the `id` in `tblColumnNames` table.
How to join these two tables so that the resulting columns are the rows of `tblColumnNames` and respective values are taken from the Value column of `tblValues` :

```
result
------------------------------
colummnName1        columnName2         columnName3

177                 abcde               123
40                  xyz                 321
```

EDIT:  The number of rows in `tblColumnNames` will constantly change.

Comment: SQL queries do not have dynamic column names.  If you want to have dynamic names, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez That question is looking for alternatives to PIVOT. My question is looking for a solution in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @ColNames NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
SELECT @ColNames = @ColNames + '['+ColumnName  +']'+ ', 'FROM tblColumnNames ORDER BY id
SET @ColNames = LEFT(@ColNames, LEN(@ColNames)-1)

DECLARE @TheQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TheQuery = 'SELECT PVT.* FROM 
(SELECT V.Value, (V.id - V.ColumnId) RowGroupID, C.ColumnName FROM 
    tblValues V INNER JOIN tblColumnNames C ON V.ColumnId = C.id ) AS SRC 
        PIVOT ( MAX(VALUE) FOR ColumnName IN ('+ @ColNames +')) PVT'

EXEC sp_executesql @TheQuery
```

Result

```
RowGroupID  columnName1 columnName2 columnName3
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
51          177         abcde       123
54          40          xyz         321
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that the number of rows in tblColumnNames (and therefore columns for the resultant table) will constantly change

Comment: Thank you, so basically it was about `pivot` and dynamically generating column names