# Presenting data horizontally and not vertically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm fairly new to SQL, but with this my IT department has asked if I could help out as they are not at full strength.

We have a table called dbo_Xrefs which holds all of our competitors cross references so there is a lot of duplicated data see **fig 1**, what I need is my data to read like **fig 2**.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Fig1

PartNo      CompName             CompNo
BC2095      A.B.S.               520831
BC2095      amk                  TCA3135
BC2095      APEC braking         LCA235
BC2095      ATE                  220635
BC2095      ATE                  24.3384-1755.7
BC2095      AUDI                 1K0615423A
BC2095      AUDI                 1K0615423D
BC2095      AUDI                 1K0615423J


Fig2

PartNo  amk     ATE     ATE1            AUDI        AUDI 1      AUDI 2                  
BC2095  TCA3135 220635  24.3384-1755.7  1K0615423A  1K0615423D  1K0615423J
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images - or, even worse - links to images.

Comment: This answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391146/transform-rows-into-columns-ms-sql/46391999#comment79741931_46391999

Comment: Likely that a `PIVOT` would be what you are after but I suspect you will need to dynamically generate it based on the Comp Name values. Can you supply more detail from the Xref table (as formatted text as jarlh says)

Comment: Put the table in Excel and use a pivot table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to number each `CompName` partitioned by `PartNo,CompName` (and -1 to start from 0) for use with [**`pivot()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

I have used `isnull(nullif(...,0,'') to turn`0`s into empty strings.

For a dynamic pivot using your example data:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);

  select @cols = stuff((
      select distinct 
        ',' + quotename(CompName
            +isnull(nullif(convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
                partition by PartNo,CompName
                order by     CompNo 
            )-1),0),'')
            )
      from Xrefs
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'');

select @sql = '
 select PartNo, ' + @cols + '
 from (
    select 
        PartNo
      , rn=CompName+isnull(nullif(convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
          partition by PartNo,CompName 
          order by     CompNo 
          )-1),0),'''')
      , CompNo
    from Xrefs
      ) as a
 pivot (max([CompNo]) for [rn] in (' + @cols + ') ) p';
 select @sql as CodeGenerated;
 exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XMXA2432

returns:

```
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
| PartNo | A.B.S. |   amk   | APEC braking |  ATE   |      ATE1      |    AUDI    |   AUDI1    |   AUDI2    |
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
| BC2095 | 520831 | TCA3135 | LCA235       | 220635 | 24.3384-1755.7 | 1K0615423A | 1K0615423D | 1K0615423J |
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try dynamic query like below:

```
CREATE table source_table (PartNo VARCHAR(10),CompName varchar(100),CompNo varchar(100));
INSERT INTO source_table values
('BC2095','A.B.S','520831'),
('BC2095','aml','TCA3135'),
('BC2095','Apec braking','LCA235');



DECLARE @listCompName VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listCompName= 
     COALESCE(@listCompName+'],[','') + CompName
FROM source_table
SET @listCompName='['+@listCompName+']'
DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(MAX)



SELECT @qry=
'select PartNo,'+@listCompName+' from'+
'('+
  'select '+
    'PartNo,CompName,CompNo '+
  'from source_table'+
')src '+
'pivot'+
'( MAX(CompNo) FOR CompName in ('+@listCompName+') )p'
exec(@qry)
```

<kbd>**[working demo](http://rextester.com/QBSL77241)**</kbd>